# Character patterns in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to get the following character pattern as follows by only using "for" or "while" loops but no "if" or "if-else" statements: (Mentioned in code block)

It's difficult for me to figure out a way to make the first character appear as blank space or represent it even as a null character. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch[6], j='\0';
    int p,q,n,i;
    printf("Enter a character\n");
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
    {
        scanf_s(" %c", &ch[n], 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (p = 4; p >= i; p--)
        {
            printf("%c", ch[p+1]-1);// _-->A blank space       
        }                           // BA                
        printf("\n");               // CBA      
    }                               // DCBA
                                    // EDCBA
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong — can you help?

Comment: `scanf_s(" %c", &ch[n], 1);` is that normal: `" %c"`?

Comment: Using `scanf_s(" %c", &ch[n], 1)` means any leading white space is skipped before the character is read.  That means you'll never get a single blank into your variables while using that format string.  It also seems funny to prompt for 'a character' and then require the user to enter 5 characters.  You should also check that `scanf_s()` succeeds; test that it returns 1, and do something (like exit with an error message) if it doesn't.

Comment: Are you missing a case from your output (the one with just `A`)?

Comment: @Ricky It is not clear why you enter all 5 characters when the character pattern can be built using only one character.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Well thats the exercise, it asks you to input the characters and then print the pattern

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks to remind me. I have edited the program block that inlcude the pattern. Thats the output i m seeking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this

```
printf("\n");
for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (p = 4; p >= i; p--)
    {
        printf("%c", ch[p+1]-1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

for this

```
printf("\n_\n");
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    for (p = i; p >= 0; p--) {
        printf("%c", ch[p]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And got this output (console):

> Enter a character
>
> ABCDE
>
> _
>
> BA
>
> CBA
>
> DCBA
>
> EDCBA

Comment: Yes thanks, i had the same idea but then my college professor didnt agree with that printf statement.. But thanks helping..

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main(void){
    char ch[SIZE+1] = {0};
    int i;

    printf("Enter a character\n");
    for (i = SIZE-1; i >= 0; --i){
        scanf_s(" %c", &ch[i], 1);
    }
    printf(" \n");
    for (i = SIZE-2; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%s\n", ch + i);
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: my idea is `printf(" \n");`. Description does not seem necessary.